# Session getPermissions() returns empty list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to make a facebook connection in my android app. I suppressed SSO and currently using webview login. I'm successfully logged in but when I used

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

this one for `publishStory()` I get no permissions and it causes exceptions. Also I have sessions's token value : ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED

Comment: have you set permission to publish ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the permissions list you've requested?
Notice that you can't request publish_stream / any publish actions in the new Facebook SDK (3), according to their docs you should use **Session.requestNewPublishPermissions** method for that.

Your access_token_removed message is ok and its just for the toString of the object (for security reasons) and if you'll watch the object you'll see the real access token (which is probably private).